# How to optimize the config save on Adobe Commerce 2.4.7?

Tags: magento2, optimization, async, magento2.4.7

I have Adobe Commerce 2.4.7, with 500 stores, and my store configs take almost a minute to save the configs due to the huge traffic and large database.

I heard that I could optimize it on 2.4.7. How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Adobe Commerce 2.4.7, we have [Asynchronous configuration save](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/performance-best-practices/configuration.html?lang=en#asynchronous-configuration-save-2.4.7-beta).

Saving configuration settings in deployments with more than 500 stores can be time-consuming. The new Async Config module enables asynchronous configuration save operations by running a cron job that uses a consumer to process the save operation in a message queue. AsyncConfig is disabled by default.

You can enable it by running this command below via CLI.

```
bin/magento setup:config:set --config-async 1
```

The **set** command writes the following to the `app/etc/env.php` file:

```
...
   'config' => [
       'async' => 1
   ]
```

Start the following Consumer to begin processing the messages in the queue on a first-in-first-out basis:

```
bin/magento queue:consumers:start saveConfigProcessor --max-messages=1
```